# 'SpiDev' object has no attribute 'GPIO'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use GPIO pins of raspberry pi. So for that purpose i have installed `SpiDev` python module. But when i tried to run my program i am getting error like `'module' object has no attribute 'GPIO'`.
So what should i do to get rid of this problem. My code is like as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import spidev
spi = spidev.Spidev()  # for creating spi object
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

out_1 = 7  # GPIO pin no 7
out_2 = 11 # GPIO pin no 11
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def abc(self, parameter1):
        spi.GPIO.setup(out_1, GPIO.OUT)
        spi.GPIO.output(out_1, 1)
        ....
        ....
        spi.GPIO.setup(out_2, GPIO.OUT)
        spi.GPIO.output(out_2, 1)
    ....
    ...
...
```

...

after running this code i am getting the error as follows
'SpiDev' object has no attribute 'GPIO'

Comment: I assume you're running this code from your Pi. Looks like you don't have gpio installed. Try entering these at the command line and run the code again: `sudo apt-get update` then
`sudo apt-get install python-dev` then
`sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install `RPI.gpio` package by doing `sudo easy_install RPi.gpio`
If this does'nt work try the following.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
```

I already had this situation and the first command fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no spi object above GPIO, so change this part:

```
spi.GPIO.setup(out_1, GPIO.OUT)
spi.GPIO.output(out_1, 1)
....
....
spi.GPIO.setup(out_2, GPIO.OUT)
spi.GPIO.output(out_2, 1)
```

...into this:

```
GPIO.setup(out_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(out_1, 1)
....
....
GPIO.setup(out_2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(out_2, 1)
```

Everything you need for your operations is in Rpi.GPIO module, so it's not nessesery to import spidev and create spi object.